# Enforcing a delay on textbox_textchanged

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have a barcode scanner that emulates keyboard entry. I'm using it to enter ISBN numbers into a textbox, which then performs a search for that title. I need the textbox method to wait for wither a 10 or 13 character entry before doing anything, however I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

So far, I have the following:

```
private void scanBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (scanBox.Text.Length == 10)
            {
                getRecord10();
            }
            else if (scanBox.Text.Length == 13)
            {
                getRecord13();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not in directory", "Error");
            }
        }
```

I'm considering some sort of timer implementation to hold off on that last condition, but what I really need is for the method to wait for either 10 or 13 digits. The barcode scanner emulates individual keys being pressed, which is why it is currently failing.

Comment: You can always configure a barcode scanner to send a special character to indicate the end of the response.  If it doesn't already do this, a beep is a giveaway.  A superior solution over a timer since it is fast and error-free.

Comment: @HansPassant Have you any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Just RTFM of the scanner.  They usually come with a configuration sheet, just scan a barcode on that sheet and the scanner configures itself.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, I managed to get it to send an ETX message after each barcode. Can C# differentiate between this and a carriage return?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use Timer (or DispatcherTimer in WPF). This sample app updates window's title 300ms after the last keystroke.

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer _typingTimer; // WinForms
    // System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer _typingTimer; // WPF

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void scanBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_typingTimer == null)
        {
            /* WinForms: */
            _typingTimer = new Timer();
            _typingTimer.Interval = 300;
            /* WPF: 
            _typingTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _typingTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
            */

            _typingTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.handleTypingTimerTimeout);
        }
        _typingTimer.Stop(); // Resets the timer
        _typingTimer.Tag = (sender as TextBox).Text; // This should be done with EventArgs
        _typingTimer.Start(); 
    }

    private void handleTypingTimerTimeout(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var timer = sender as Timer; // WinForms
        // var timer = sender as DispatcherTimer; // WPF
        if (timer == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Testing - updates window title
        var isbn = timer.Tag.ToString();
        windowFrame.Text = isbn; // WinForms
        // windowFrame.Title = isbn; // WPF

        // The timer must be stopped! We want to act only once per keystroke.
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

*Parts of code are taken from the Roslyn syntax visualizer*

Comment: One problem: Threading is a WPF component, and is difficult to integrate into winforms. I'm having a look now, do you have any ideas?

Comment: You're right! My bad. I'm editing the answer right now. You can use System.Windows.Forms.Timer and the implementation is very similar.

Comment: Hope the answer is complete now.

Comment: Yep. Good answer> I'd have used this (most likely) as a solution... but I realised that the scanner could be configured to send a  carriage return after each barcode. For this context, however, your answer is excellent.

Comment: That sounds like a much better solution!

Answer (score 2):

I propose a solution using [Microsoft Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx) which are available as a nuget package.

Reactive Extensions is a library to compose asynchronous and event-based programs using observable collections and LINQ-style query operators.

If you use the RX extensions your problem can be solved with just two lines of code:

Sign up for an event: here with count == 10

```
    IObservable<string> textChangedObservable =
    Observable.FromEventPattern(textBox1, "TextChanged")
    .Select(evt => ((TextBox)evt.Sender).Text).Where(x => x.Length == 10);
```

Subscribe to the Event:

```
    textChangedObservable.Subscribe(e => MessageBox.Show(e));
```

Comment: Nice idea, I'll keep this in mind if the `DispatcherTimer` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps.

```
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;

    private void scanBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (scanBox.Text.Length == 10)
        {
            //wait for 10 chars and then set the timer
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000); //adjust time based on time required to enter the last 3 chars 
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;

        if (scanBox.Text.Length == 10)
        {
            getRecord10();                
        }
        else if (scanBox.Text.Length == 13)
        {
            getRecord13();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not in directory", "Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't pretend to be an experienced programmer, but won't this exponentially increase the number of timers whenever an item is scanned?

Comment: It should create only one timer per scan. That too only when the 10th char is entered. Is it not working that way?

Comment: Let me try it out. I've just discovered the similarities between `DsipatcherTimer` and `Timer`...

Answer (score 0):

I went for the timer solution and created a simple class to wrap it up a bit more neatly.
The **TypingFinished** event is then accessed from the Form if it is needed.

The **TextChanged** event is wrapped inside the **HandleCreated** event to prevent it from being invoked when Application Settings are being set to the textbox.

**Settings.Default.Save** is called because it is always true for me, but could just as well be put in the **TypingFinished** event.

```
using YourApp.Properties;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourApp.Controls
{
    public partial class TypeDelayTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public TypeDelayTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.HandleCreated += (senderX, argsX) => { this.TextChanged += OnTextChanged; };
        }

        private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            Settings.Default.Save();
            OnTypingFinished();
        }

        public event EventHandler TypingFinished;

        protected virtual void OnTypingFinished()
        {
            TypingFinished?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Designer code:

```
namespace YourApp.Controls
{
    partial class TypeDelayTextBox
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this._timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // _timer
            // 
            this._timer.Interval = 3000;
            this._timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this._timer_Tick);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to pass an action to be invoked after the timer period.
Thanks to `Amadeusz Wieczorek` asnwer:

```
    private Timer _typingTimer;

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckTimer(() => { label1.Text = (sender as TextBox)?.Text; });
    }

    private void CheckTimer(Action act)
    {
        if (_typingTimer == null)
        {
            _typingTimer = new Timer { Interval = 350 };
            _typingTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (!(sender is Timer timer))
                    return;
                act?.Invoke();
                timer.Stop();
            };
        }
        _typingTimer.Stop();
        _typingTimer.Start();
    }
```